# concatenate variables to compare against a variable

Tags: javascript

Hi all this is simple but for some reason I can't remember how to do this I have the following code

```
            var m1q1Correct = '1';
            q = arguments[1];

            var ans = $('input[name=m' + m + 'q' + q + ']:checked', '#containerFrm').val();
            if ('m' + m + 'q' + q + 'Correct' == q) {
                alert('right');
            } else {
                alert('wrong');
            }
```

I've also tried this

```
            var ans = $('input[name=m' + m + 'q' + q + ']:checked', '#containerFrm').val();
            if (eval('m' + m + 'q' + q + 'Correct') == q) {
                alert('right');
            } else {
                alert('wrong');
            }
```

I'm trying to join m + m + q + q + Correct as the variable name, can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong

thanks

Comment: Why `eval()`? Is `"mqCorrect"` some valid/sensible JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use object storing variables map instead of separate variables. Then you don't need to apply `eval`:

```
var vars = {'m1q1Correct': '1'};
q = arguments[1];
var ans = $('input[name=m' + m + 'q' + q + ']:checked', '#containerFrm').val();
if (vars['m' + m + 'q' + q + 'Correct'] == q) {
    alert('right');
} else {
    alert('wrong');
}
```

Comment: @andrew slaughter You could upvote my answer as well if it solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Probably javascript is doing something special with character/number additions.

If m and q are just numbers, I'd convert them to string and concatenate them.

var n = num.toString();

var res = str1.concat(str2);